# Customvalidation for html checkbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

How could I validate the html checkbox in asp.net?
I've tried the following.

```
<input type="checkbox"  id="chk_rule" class="checkbox-custom" name="chk_rule"  runat="server"/>
<label for="bodycontent_chk_rule" class="checkbox-custom-label">I have read and agree to the official rules</label>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="Agreecheck" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="You have to agree the rules." ControlToValidate="chk_rule" OnServerValidate="Agreecheck_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

And the server-side validation function is following.

```
 protected void Agreecheck_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = chk_rule.Checked;
}
```

But I've got the following error.

> Message: Unable to find control id 'chk_rule' referenced by the
>   'ControlToValidate' property of 'Agreecheck'. Stack Trace: at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.CheckControlValidationProperty(String
>   name, String propertyName) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CustomValidator.ControlPropertiesValid() at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

How could I fix this?

Comment: Do you use a master page?

Comment: Please check [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASP.Net-CheckBox-Required-Validation-using-Custom-Validator-and-JavaScript.aspx)

Comment: @FarzInKanz I use master page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code, It works if you replace the checkbox with a Textbox. I think the custom validator is not for using for checkbox. So you can easily remove the problem by some jquery codes:

```
<script>
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function ()
    {
        var clientId = '<%= chk_rule.ClientID %>';
        if (!$('#' + clientId).is(':checked'))
        {
            alert('You must agree the rules');
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here is a code snippet (only for see), **you need the above code for your app**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox"  id="chk_rule" class="checkbox-custom" name="chk_rule"  runat="server"/>
<label for="bodycontent_chk_rule" class="checkbox-custom-label">I have read and agree to the official rules</label>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="btnSubmit">
<script>
        $('input[type=submit]').click(function ()
        {
            if (!$('#chk_rule').is(':checked'))
            {
                alert('You must agree the rules');
                return false;
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Now I use Master Page, It's necessary to use server-side validation. <br> Because when the browser disables the javascript, the client validation couldn't work.

Comment: There is no diffrence. I tested that in a page with master page so.

Comment: When disabling the javascript ,does the validation work?

Comment: When disabling the javascript any custom validator does not work. They work by javascript.

Comment: Without javascript you can only check in code behind is checkbox checked or not.

Comment: Yeah. It helps me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CustomValidator` to see if the CheckBox is checked.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Check me please" />

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Checkbox not checked" ClientValidationFunction="validateCheckBox"></asp:CustomValidator>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateCheckBox(sender, args) {
        args.IsValid = document.getElementById("<%=CheckBox1.ClientID %>").checked;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How could I use server-side valid function?